# Is it ok to add code with the sole purpose of making it easier to test?

Tags: testing

My situation, as some background:

I'm writing a small javascript library which uses `window.requestAnimationFrame` to perform its animation loop. Because that function isn't standardised across the browsers yet, internally in the library it creates a polyfill-ish function in a closure.

```
var requestAnim = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || ...
    || function () { ... };
```

The issue here is that this makes it quite hard for me to test this code now. Previously, when it was using `setTimeout`, I would override that global function in the tests to simulate a number of frames passing synchronously.

**Anyway, to the point of the question:**

Right now, it seems like my options are either to leave some of my code untested, or to add extraneous features to the library with the sole purpose of making it easier to test. Neither of these options sound that great to me.

Without worrying too much about my specific case, **in general**, what should you do in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is ok.

We don't write tests for the sake of testing. Testing is an acknowledgement of the fact that we aren't brillant enough to write and maintain code perfectly without safety checks. All test code serves one purpose and only one: to make a better product. This is true whether it lives in the /test folder or in the /src folder. Therefore it is a mistake to think "This is never called in production, therefore it is wrong to put it into /src!"

To be sure, there are other trade-offs to make, e.g. size (in an embedded product it makes a lot of sense to try everything you can to keep the /src folder small). But that is a completely different reason than merely "It's test-related".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's fine to add testing code (unless some micro-optimisation is something you're testing). As Kilian was saying, nobody is perfect; this is the reason we do testing in the first place.

I +1d Kilian's answer, but I'd like to add my own ideas too:

In general, what situations would there be code that you cannot (with ease) test? This would be code that only runs under conditions, which you can't re-create on your testing machine? Perhaps it would be easier to set a variable to decide whether this code should run or not, then you can set a breakpoint and change this variable when debugging (in your JavaScript case, using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools?)

Or, like you say, add some testing code - a set of flags maybe at the top of the script, to keep it neat? Then your if statements could be something like

```
if(shouldRunThisCode || isTestingThisCode) {
    doThisCode();
}
```

**In short:** Ofcourse it's fine to add code for the purpose of testing. I can't think of any scenarios where testing the code will require adding much code at all though. If the code is implemented and intended to run at some point under certain conditions anyway, it can never be too hard to test.

Comment: I guess the issue I had was to do with muddying the interface my library presented to the user.

Comment: You did ask without worrying to much about your specific case ;) Maybe you could write a testing wrapper library that isn't included in the release version?

Answer (score 0):

In general, code that is hard to test is badly written.[1](http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2007/09/the-deep-synerg.html)  It is superior to find the design problems your test difficulties are telling you about and fix those than to add code "just to make testing easier".  Sometimes we do that anyway, because we construe the design problems as too difficult to fix -- but it should be the second choice.  In your case, it sounds like the bad design you're exposing is in a library outside your control.  In this case, adding code "just to make testing easier" is probably the best choice; you are unlikely to have enough control over an external library to improve its design.